# I want make a function which will find the max value in array

Tags: python, arrays, max, element

```
def max(list):
    max_element = list[0]

    for i in range(1, len(list)):
        if list[i] > max_element:
            max_element = list[i]


print(max_element)

print(max([1, 2, 8, 4]))

#NameError: name 'max_element' is not defined
```

how to fix it?

Comment: `max_element` is locally defined within the function. You are trying to access it outside of its scope.  You don't even need to call that.  Just make sure you return `max_element` in your function and use the second print statement.

Comment: Python has a built-in function to do what you want: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max

Comment: remove `print(max_element)` since it does not make sense at all.

Comment: max_element's scope is restricted to the function since it is defined inside the function. you cannot access it outside. Python is not bash or Lua.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing first, don't override python's globals. Python provides a `max` function by default.

```
def max_number(list):
    max_element = list[0]

    for i in range(1, len(list)):
        if list[i] > max_element:
            max_element = list[i]
    return max_element

print(max_number([1, 2, 8, 4]))
```

You can't just use a variable not in your scope, max_element variable is only available in your `max_element` function's scope, to actually retrieve the value, you need to return it.

Comment: thanks a lot! so, the problem was because of the name of my function?

Comment: No, the problem was because you were trying to print `max_element`, which you don't have access to outside your function. If you did `print(max_element)` inside the function ,it wouldn't error out. In both cases, don't override python globals.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like that:

```
def max(list):
    max_element = list[0]

    for i in range(1, len(list)):
        if list[i] > max_element:
            max_element = list[i]
    return max_element


print(max([1, 2, 8, 4]))
```

Comment: your function should pass the max_element outside through a return

Comment: sry left one space out

Comment: but you should just use the buildin `max()` function

Answer (score 0):

'max_element' is a variable inside of your function scope so when you try to print it outside of the function your computer doesn't know what it is. 
You want to print inside function after the loop is complete to have it print when run.

```
def max(list):
  max_element = list[0]
  for i in range(1, len(list)):
    if list[i] > max_element:
      max_element = list[i]
  print(max_element)   

max([1, 2, 8, 4])
```

Comment: you really dont want to print the value inside the function. The reason why you implement this function is that you want to get the biggest item. so you should return it